# How to use client socket as a server socket python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I like to have one port that first use for connect to another server and after that this port use to be a server and another clients connect to it.


I used python socket for client now I want to use it for server socket.

my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file
import socket               # Import socket module
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12349
portt = 12341               # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, portt))       # Bind to the port

s.connect((host, port))
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
c, addr = s.accept()        # Establish connection with client.
print c
print 'Got connection from', addr
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

and the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 12, in <module>
    s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

How can I do that.
thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. Seems to me that you are mixing client and server code in the same app.

For reference, you can create a simple echo server like this:

```
import socket

HOST = ''                
PORT = 12349     
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

And a simple echo client like this:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 12349              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

Comment: I like to have one port that first use for connect to another server and after that this port use to be a server and another clients connect to it.

Comment: In such case, you need to close the connection and start listening on the same port. You can not use the same port with server and the client at the same time.